# SlickGrid custom CSS issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, slickgrid

I am using the latest version of slickgrid and am encountering an issue when implementing the latest jquery and jquery ui along with the custom ui css. I have tried using the jquery ui css with worse results. First image is with custom CSS and the second is with jquery ui css 1.10.4. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

[image: With the Custom UI.css from SlickGrid]

[image: With UI 1.10.4 css]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is an issue directly related to bootstrap and slickgrid. [issue#742](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/742)
 I fixed it by adding

```
.slickgrid, 
.slickgrid *,
.slick-header-column {
 box-sizing: content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
 }
```

to the slickgrid.css file.